# Wildfly 9.0.x Excluding Infinispan

Tags: dependencies, infinispan, wildfly-9, conflicting-libraries

I m working with Wildfly 9 and i developed a jar imported as dependency by a web application (.war). The jar uses infinispan 8.1.0 while the application server uses the 7.2.3.

i 've written the following jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.infinispan" /> 
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and i have put it in the META-INF folder of the jar library.

When i deploy the web application and i invoke the SessionManager initialization i get this exception:

```
20:53:09,040 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole) org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to construct a GlobalComponentRegistry!
20:53:09,040 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.<init>(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:136) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
20:53:09,041 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:214) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
20:53:09,041 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:199) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
```

So it seems that server still want to use its libraries.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the context, I assume this `SessionManager` is one of the classes present in your jar (which was added as a dependency to the war file).

By default you should have no access to classes from Infinispan embedded into Wildfly (unless you have a dependency declared in `MANIFEST.MF` or it's specified in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`).

Could you please paste full stacktrace? Also I would be interested in server configuration and any specific things of your app.